# How to add incremental value inside Instream or list stream?

Tags: java, list, for-loop, java-8, java-stream

How to add increment value inside IntStream or list stream?

```
List<TestInstance> testInstances = IntStream.range(0, rankedItem.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> TestInstance.fromItem(rankedItem.get(i), filteredItems.containsKey(rankedItem.get(i).getItem().getId())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        int rank = MIN_RANK_VALUE;
        for (TestInstance testInstance : testInstances) {
            testInstance.getRank().put(rankerName, rank++);
        }
```

Right now I'm doing it in 2 for loops. Is there any way I could do it in a single iteration?

Comment: You may use an `AtomicInteger` and its `getAndIncrement` method. You are not using its atomicness (unless you use a parallel stream), but its other virtues make it fine for your purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Since the ranks you are trying to set are in the order of the items in the initial list, they are equal to `MIN_RANK_VALUE` + the position in the list, so you can simply reuse `i` to compute the rank:

```
List<TestInstance> testInstances = IntStream.range(0, rankedItem.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> {
        TestInstance t = TestInstance.fromItem(rankedItem.get(i), filteredItems.containsKey(rankedItem.get(i).getItem().getId()));
        t.getRank().put(rankerName, MIN_RANK_VALUE + i);
        return t;
    })
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Ideally, you would modify `fromItem()` to take the rank as parameter so that you can keep a single line for the lambda.

Comment: It gives me error saying get(int) in List can not be applied to (<lambda>) for rankedItem.get(i)

Comment: @user3407267 There was a missing `}`, maybe that fixes it? I cannot really test it since you didn't provide the full code.